# Fetching Sharepoint Groupnames and users in group using web services in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to fetch all the Sharepoint groups and users in the groups using a Web service. I added web server /_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx. Then I have writen below code.

```
WebReference.UserGroup Group = new GetGorupNames.WebReference.UserGroup();
XmlNode Users = Group.GetGroupCollectionFromWeb();
```

I am unaware of further procedure.As this is my first time using web service in sharepoint. Any help provided related to xml and web service will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for above query I find a wonderful article which made my task easy.
Sharing with all. PSB link.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/export-sharepoint-users-and-groups-to-excel-using-powershell.html